# Viewing contents of a .jar file

Tags: java, jar, viewer

What would be the easiest way to view classes, methods, properties, etc. inside a jar file?
I'm looking for something equivalent to the very useful  *Lutz Roeder .NET Reflector*  - for Java

Comment: @KolobCanyon true, but they top rated answer was submitted the same day as this one was asked

Comment: The answer comes from： [https://superuser.com/a/808938/1045397](https://superuser.com/a/808938/1045397) You can do it with vim vim file_name.jar

Answer (score 350):

Using the JDK, `jar -tf` will list the files in the jar. `javap` will give you more details from a particular class file.

Comment: @salvob You don't need the hyphen as it takes after `tar` with the options mandatory.

Comment: FYI, You may need to add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk<version>\bin` to your system or user PATH environment variable before you can use `jar` as a system command. (Where <version> is your jdk version-build number. Check it in `C:\Program Files\Java`)

Comment: javap example: javap -classpath test.jar com.yourpackage.HelloWorld

Comment: to see the content of a non-class files (like manifest) you would like to do something like this: tar -xOzf  test.jar `jar tf test.jar | grep MANIFEST`

Comment: @mPrinC thank you, IMO your comment is the best answer.

Answer (score 64):

I usually open them with 7-Zip... It allows at least to see packages and classes and resources.
Should I need to see methods or fields, I would use Jad but of course, it is better to rely on (good) JavaDoc...

Now, somewhere on SO was mentioned some Eclipse plug-ins, to find in which jar file a class is located, perhaps they can do more (ie. what you requested).

[EDIT] Reference to SO thread. Not what is asked, but somehow related, thus useful: [Java: How do I know which jar file to use given a class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275120/java-how-do-i-know-which-jar-file-to-use-given-a-class-name)

Comment: The link to the Jad site has been removed as the URL is parked. It can be still found at https://web.archive.org/web/20080106184313/http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html but Jad is outdated today, anyway.

Answer (score 53):

> In case someone don't know this already, a JAR file is just a ZIP file
>   that contains the program's classes, resources, etc., and some
>   metadata. You can extract one to see how it's put together.

Hence I am using `unzip` command which is easy to remember and use.

`unzip -l <jar-file-name>.jar`

For example, if you have a jar file with name `test.jar` then `unzip -l test.jar` will list all the content of jar file.

**While all other answers are great, but in most of them, you would have to use some software like `7 zip` or `JDK` or some other eclipse tool while this doesn't require you to have any of these big s/w and it comes by default in linux and mac so its very lightweight and handy to use**.

You can also use `zipinfo <your jar file>`. if your OS supports this.

Comment: @Boop thanks for the suggestion. will add it to my answer

Comment: If the file explorer supports zip, renaming the jar to .zip works too (for example on windows)

Answer (score 37):

What I use personally is JD-GUI. It is a free 'decompiler', as it allows you to see the source code, classes, and objects in the classes, as well as see the file structure in a tree menu to the left. However, it does not allow  you to modify the classes directly.

JD-GUI's website: http://jd.benow.ca/

Comment: This works cross-platform while 7-Zip mentioned in another answer is Windows-specific.

Comment: I used *Archive Utility* on OS X, worked fine. Most (un)zip utilities should work, regardless of platform.

Answer (score 26):

```
jar -tvf file_name.jar
```

above will only **print names of the files**.

To view the content of files, you can **extract the files in a folder** by:

```
jar -xvf file_name.jar
```

this will unzip jar file & put the content in same directory where you are running this.

Or in Windows rename .jar file to .zip & then you can unzip to extract & view the content of jar file. As jar is internally a zip file.

Answer (score 18):

#### Method names, fields, etc.

By adding a jar to a project in an IDE, you can usually see methods and field names, but not the detailed implementation. NetBeans can do it, Eclipse probably, IntelliJ probably, etc. You can browse the jar structure directly within the IDE.

#### Just the contents

For anything such as viewing the contents, you could use :

- `jar tvf jarfile.jar`
- winzip or any zip tool

#### The source code

To access source code, you would use a decompiler such as JAD or one of its frontends or another decompiler. If the code is obfuscated, then ...

Answer (score 13):

Extending Tom Hawtin answer, you can pipe the listing to filter out desired class or files:

`jar tf my-fat-jar-file.jar | grep filename`

This should work on bash/zsh and similars, or emacs' eshell.

Additional information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html

Answer (score 8):

**[Use WinRar](http://www.rarlab.com)**. It will open the folder structure for you in intact manner. Also allows in-archive editing, while preserving paths.

Afterall, a JAR file is a ZIP archive only.

Answer (score 6):

If you like to see whats inside, simply rename as first option below..

1. `F2 & Rename to jarfile.zip`    //Use any unzipper...
2. `jar tvf jarfile.jar`
3. `jar tf jarfile.jar`

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you want to see not only classes but also methods, properties and so on. The only tool I know that can do it is Eclipse - if you add a jar to project classpath, you would be able to browse its classes with methods and properties using usual package explorer.

Anyway, this is a good idea for a good standalone Java tool

Comment: Note that the jar needs to be in "Referenced libraries" folder, not just "libs". And in the case of Apache Commons library, you don't browse the source.jar, you browse the original and then attach the source when Eclipse asks.

Answer (score 4):

Jad is klunky and no longer maintained. I've switched to ["Java Decompiler"](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/), which has a slick UI and support for new language features.

Every decompiler I've used, though, runs into code it doesn't successfully decompile. For those, it helps to understand the disassembled Java byte code produced by the standard JDK tool, [javap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html).

Answer (score 3):

Well, a jar-file is just a zip-file, so if you unzip it (with your favorite unzipping utility), you get all the files inside.

If you want to look inside the class files to see the methods, you'll need a tool for that. As PhiLho mentions, Eclipse is able to do that (by default), and I would think most Java IDEs are capable of that.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse 3.4 do

1. Drag the jar file in question into a Java project.  A copy of the jar file appears.
2. Right click on the jar file, and choose "Build Path" -> "Add to Build Path".
3. Jar file is moved to "Referenced Libraries" node, where it can be opened and navigated in the Project Explorer pane.

If seeing source code too is an issue, open a new question.

For navigation on Jar-file level (as a zip file) I use 7zip which works very well, and allows seeing and editing entries which is great for trouble shooting.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in windows and using powershell and you are looking for a file in a jar you can do:

```
jar -tf .\[JAR_NAME] | where {$_ -match "[FILENAME]"}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to open the perspective in "Package explorer". Doing this you can see the structure of your jar with class details. For this check the library folder in your project using package explorer.

Window>>Show View>>Other>>Java>>Package Explorer

Another way  is, you can use JarPlug as a eclipse plugin. This works in eclipse/springsource

http://jar-plug.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

My requirement was to view the content of a file (like a property file) inside the jar, without actually extracting the jar. If anyone reached this thread just like me, try this command -

```
unzip -p myjar.jar myfile.txt
```

This worked well for me!

Answer (score 3):

This [Jar Explorer](http://dst.in.ua/jarexp/index.html?l=en) is good enough. 
Supports three decompiler types: JD, Procyon and Fernflower.
Allows to search files and duplicates in any java archive.
Also user can modify jar by D&D files and edit some non-class files.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: i always used "jd-gui". i did'nt knew about this. thanks. thanks for info

Answer (score 3):

You can view JAR files like ZIP files from Windows Explorer by doing the following:

- Run Command Prompt as Administrator
- From the command line, enter:

  assoc .jar=CompressedFolder
- While you are at it, you might as well do the same for WAR and EAR files:

  assoc .war=CompressedFolder

  assoc .ear=CompressedFolder

Answer (score 2):

You can open them with most decompression utilities these days, then just get something like [DJ Java Decompiler](http://www.neshkov.com/) if you want to view the source.

Answer (score 2):

[Bndtools](http://bndtools.org/index.html) provides a free JAR viewer plugin for Eclipse.

Add the [Eclipse update site](http://bndtools.org/installation.html#update-site) and install only the viewer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think Java Decomplier is your best option you can download from here: http://jd.benow.ca/
[image: Preview]

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to view classes, methods, properties, etc. inside a jar file is using programs like '[winrar](https://www.win-rar.com/start.html?&L=5)' and '[7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html)'.

- Download winrar or 7-zip program if it's not installed
- Then right click to your jar file
- Click open with winrar or 7-zip

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [JAR Browser](http://jarbrowser.sourceforge.net/), it has a simple interface where you can browse multiple JARs, and search for a specific class across multiple JARs simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse 3.4 JDT

It is not the quickest way because you have to drag it into your eclipse first.
But you will have full java class browsing, even with decompile enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I've set the default action in windows to "Open with WinZip".  This makes it easy to manage JARs as archives.  You can even add/remove files manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [JarSpy](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=42094).  There is an IDEA plugin version of it that I use.

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE should also support this. My IDE (SlickeEdit) calls it a "tag library." Simply add a tag library for the jar file, and you should be able to browse the classes and methods in a hierarchical manner.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac there's [Jarzilla](http://code.google.com/p/jarzilla/)

Answer (score 0):

I use JarExplorer or [JarVisualizer](http://code.google.com/p/jarvisualizer/).

Answer (score 0):

Most people have answered this correctly here is one solution for linux if you don't even know where your jar path is or your JDK path is different on each host

```
$(find / -type f -name "jar" 2>&1 |grep '/JDK' |head -1 ) tf FULLY_QUALIFIED_NAME_TO_YOUR_FILE
```

Answer (score -1):

`java -xf some-j.jar` will unzip a JAR file.

Comment: it's jar -xf someJar.jar