# JAVA can I get the librarys of an exported project(runnable jar)?

Tags: java, jar

My friend sent me a runnable jar he made and I would like to view the librarys he used in the jar.
I was wondering if that was possible? if so how could I view/get the files?
thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing contents of a .jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320510/viewing-contents-of-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

If the runnable jar has been created using Maven, you could find useful information in the META-INF/maven folder.

It contains the pom.xml and a simple pom.properties for every jar that has been exploded inside.