# How to check what is inside a JAR archive that you are running?

Tags: java

I can only seem to get the folder of the jar and not the contents inside.

Basically someone cracked my program and they put a File inside the JAR which the program loaded from, I want to add some sneaky checks inside an API that I use to check to see if there is an extra File inside and disable the product if so.

So - how can I check for any .json or .file files inside a JAR file? I looked at this, [Viewing contents of a .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320510/viewing-contents-of-a-jar-file), but didn't get the answer I wanted.

Thanks.

Comment: [Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/)

Comment: The answers in the post you linked will be the same answers you'll get here: 1. Use `jar tf your-jar` 2. Extract using software like 7-Zip or WinRar 3. Use a decompiler such as JAD. You could also load the contents at runtime using a `JarFile`, and you could obfuscate your code to deter hackers.

Comment: To be honest, this is what JAR signing and checksums are for

Answer (score 0):

In order to verify that a jar is unaltered, it is more common and reliable to either sign your jar or use a checksum like SHA256.

Signing your jar acts like a seal that is broken if the jar is opened. Signing a jar takes money and time, so it is typically only used for production-type software.

A checksum will be computed based on all binary and otherwise contents. If the contents change, so will the checksum. Using a SHA256 checksum will result in the near-impossibility of a duplicated hash, especially with working code.

Comment: I am not spending money on it - how can I manually check if the jar has an extra file in it? I'm also planning to edit the API and insert this code, since it's a big API, nobody would know that it is hidden in there.

Comment: Internally run the checksum on the folder you care about. If the checksum changed, the contents changed (i.e. addition/deletion).