# how can we check my PROD build files does not have test cases inside

Tags: java, spring-boot-test

how can we check my PROD build files does not have test cases inside

i am creating a docker image with my jar file that going to be deployed in OCP pod. However, i should make sure that image should not contain the java test cases inside that build to maintain the security in ISRM Standard

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320510/viewing-contents-of-a-jar-file

Comment: hey [keerthana dharmaraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23507187/keerthana-dharmaraj) welcome to stackoverflow. please provide more information about your problem like the Dockerfile or pom.xml and ...  so the community can help you better. thanks for your contribution.