# searching through .jar files eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm porting a few java gwt projects into eclipse and the projects depends on many external .jar files, some of the dependencies seem to be dynamically linked so eclipse isn't picking up the missing links while running the ide.

At run time, I often get exceptions that say for example 'import bar.foo.XML' is missing or some FooBar class definition is missing and it always takes me a while to figure out which .jar file these classes/libraries belong to so I can add them to the run path.

Is there a quick way to search which .jar files contain what classes and what other library they depend on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An oldie, but still good, and integrated into eclipse:

<del>[JarClassFinder](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/jarclassfinder/download):</del>

[image]

Update 2013: the project still exists in a different form as an independent app [JarClassFinder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jarclassfinder/).
In term of Eclipse plugin, it is no longer maintained, and you only have variant like "[BundleclassFinder](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/bclassfinder/index.php?title=Main_Page)".

Other (manual) ways to find a class within jars: "[Java: How do I know which jar file to use given a class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275120/java-how-do-i-know-which-jar-file-to-use-given-a-class-name)"

Comment: cant find it now. any similar recent software?

Answer (score 0):

You need a tool like [Jar Analyzer](http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just mark all the jar-files in Eclipse and right-click->add to Build Path?

Comment: I personally hate having unnecessary .jars in my build path, it's always great if you know what you actually need