# How do I find out what Library a method is in?

Tags: java, jar, junit, jmock

Specifically: what library is MockObjectTestCase in?

I'm following this link: http://therning.org/niklas/2005/05/jmock-solid-testing/

Is there an easy way to find out this kind of information? IS there a way to search through all of the files in the JMock jars?

I have jmock-2.5.1.jar, jmock-junit4-2.5.1.jar, junit-4.10.jar in my build path, but eclipse is not finding MockObjectTestCase as a super class selection for me to extend

Thanks

Comment: Answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275120/java-how-do-i-know-which-jar-file-to-use-given-a-class-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the package seems to be:
`org.jmock.cglib.MockObjectTestCase`

And according to
http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.jmock.MockObjectTestCase
It seems to be found in 1.x versions of Jmock.

That post you linked to seems very old. Since you're using a later version that class might not exist anymore.

Comment: What exactly did you google? Just MockObjectTestCase?
That gives the link to the javadoc:http://www.jmock.org/javadoc/2.0.0/org/jmock/integration/junit3/MockObjectTestCase.html

Is the library in the javadoc?

Comment: @ericf Sorry about that, I've updated with another link. I doubt that the class exist in jmock-2.5.1.

Comment: I also noticed a program called JarClassFinder. It is nice.

Comment: For further reference, where did you find the class you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I use [findjar](http://www.findjar.com/index.x) for this sort of thing. In your case:

- http://www.findjar.com/index.x?query=MockObjectTestCase

Click on any of the results (i have no idea why there are so many - the links all lead to the same place), and you get a list of jars. Click through from those, and you have some information about the jars.

I suspect both findJAR and jarFinder are mostly indexing artefacts from Maven Central. You can search that directly:

- http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch|gav

Which in your case:

- http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|c%3A%22MockObjectTestCase%22

Finds quite a number of results.

Answer (score 1):

Google works well.  But sometimes you have to revert to the data you have on your disk:

```
jar tf SomeJarFile.jar | grep ClassName
```

Iterate over all your jars.