# NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/serializer/StringDecoder after exporting jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have exported two jars of two apps I have in the same Kafka/Spark Streaming project. 
The jar with the Kafka Producer works fine. The jar with the Spark Consumer returns this error:

> NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/serializer/StringDecoder

They share the same dependencies folder, which I have obviously exported in order to make the jars work outside Eclipse.

In Eclipse they both work fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: do you kafka jar in your class path ?

Comment: I've got spark-streaming-kafka in the classpath. Isn't it enough?

Comment: but stringDecoder is part of kafka module just check whether kafka-streaming contains String decoder

Comment: I looked into the jar of spark-streaming-kafka and it contains the .class file that is named in the error: `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:55)`. So I can't understand why he misses this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Kafka itself in the class path, not just spark-streaming-kafka. In Eclipse you do, because your build system retrieves all dependencies, and Eclipse integrates with it.

> I looked into the jar of spark-streaming-kafka and it contains the .class file that is named in the error: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(Ka‌​fkaUtils.scala:55). So I can't understand why he misses this class.

Presumably you mean that contains `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$`, but when JVM tries to load it, it discovers that it needs other classes, including `kafka.serializer.StringDecoder`, which is not there.

Comment: Thanks for helping. So, which jars you think I need to import to fix this? Because I've been having troubles with incompatible versions of Spark and Kafka.

Comment: You really don't provide enough information to answer this. But see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275120/java-how-do-i-know-which-jar-file-to-use-given-a-class-name.

Comment: Solved. I missed all the Kafka jars, which I imported only with Maven dependencies, so Eclipse couldn't actually export them.
Your hint solved the issue, so thank you so much and well deserved bounty.