# eclipse, how to find which classes are used from jar library

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Is is possible in eclipse find all the imports in the project for a certain JAR library? I.e. find out which classes of library are used and which not. Or is there any command line tool to achieve such a task.

Comment: I hope this question will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275120/java-how-do-i-know-which-jar-file-to-use-given-a-class-name

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer, but I search the main package used by the class

For example for commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar I search in my Project `org.apache.commons.fileupload`

Answer (score -2):

Click on class name in import statement and it will gets open in class editor.

then find the jar name below the 'Source not found' sentence and the open that jar using Jd-gui.

Comment: I don't want to find the jar of an import, but find all the imports from jar